# Determining Fermi Energy for a specific $E(k)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, fermi-energy

I am currently taking an introductory course on solid state physics. One of the problems I came by while studying asks the following:

Suppose we have a 1 dimensional solid of length L, with N primitive cells and one electron per primitive cell, and a separation between cells of $a$. Suppose also that there is only one energy band, with

$$ 
E(k) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} k^2\left(1-\frac{a^2}{2\pi^2}k^2\right),\ |k| \leq\frac{\pi}{a}
$$

It asks for both the Fermi wave vector $k_F$ and the Fermi Energy $E_F$. Now, this function $E(k)$ isn't increasing in the first Brillouin zone, as it can be easily seen that (starting at $k=0$ and going to $k = \frac{\pi}{a}$, for instance) it first increases from $E(0) = 0$ until it arrives at a maximum for $k < \frac{\pi}{a}$ and then it decreases until $E(\frac{\pi}{a}) = 0$. Thus, I don't even see how $k_F$ would be defined in this case, and I don't know how to compute $E_F$.

Comment: I propose a sort of numerical algorithm. You have $2N$ electronic states labeled by $k_j = -\pi/a + j\Delta k$, where $\Delta k=2\pi/L$, each one being 2-fold degenerate due to the electronic spin. You have $N$ electrons, so the Fermi energy is the $N/2$-th element of the list $E(k_j)$ sorted in ascending order. The Fermi momenta $k_F$ are the solutions to the equation $E(k_F) = E_F$. Probably you can also make progresses with analytic methods, I will try later